# How to continue "For-Loop" if function exit

Tags: php, codeigniter, return, exit

i want to continue my for-loop if called function execute **exit();** statement.

Note:
Remaining code lines should not be processed when $i=2; so, the main thing i need help to exit my function but not **for-loop**.

Moreover, i have lot of conditions so i can not use if-else.

i have already tried **return;** statement but with the return; statement function executes remaining lines of code that's the main issue!.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

For example

```
 for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
   $this->calculate($i);
 }

 function calculate($counter){
 if($counter==2){
  exit(0);
 }
  echo "My remaining code lines";
}
```

Comment: Use `return` to exit the function call, not the whole script.

Comment: Hi @MattClark, with use of return function executes remaining code lines. thats the main issue.

Comment: You want to exit. Return brings us back to the loop which allows us to continue going through it but you say "you dont want to execute remaining code lines", and in your question you say that you want to "exit my function but not for-loop." So which is it? Break cuts us out of the foreach for good, and continue allows us to continue with the foreach but go through the rest of the lines....

Comment: Yes @Alex, i want to break function execution if $counter=2, so, according to my practice we can not use **break** and **continue** statements outside the loop. and as we know exit() function terminate all script, and return statement executes "remaining lines of code". so what should i do to accomplish my requirement???

Comment: Bro read my updated answer, I even attached a *running* code example (one with break and one with continue). We just let the for function know to break by returning false and looking for a false return; entirely different than just returning

Comment: @Alex Great! let me try it. i will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

After your comment. We have to let the for loop know that we don't want to continue. Since the logic is separated we can do something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if ($this->calculate($i) == false) {
        break;
    }
}

function calculate($counter) {
    if ($counter == 2) {
        return false;
    }
    echo "My remaining code lines";
    return true;
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Do not exit the function. It halts any further processing.

Simply `return`:

```
function calculate($counter){
 if($counter==2){
  return;
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, with the use of return; statement, function executes remaining lines of code. thats the main issue.

Comment: Updated, is that helpful?

Comment: Dear @Alex, with the use of return; statement, function executes remaining lines of code

Comment: Not when it is used like this.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/05b8fea2dc612878bbb3c29668635e530ea20696

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `exit` use `return` because `exit` terminates the execution, whilst `return` only exists the current function.

And instead of `if-else` you can use [`swtich-case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
   if(!$this->calculate($i))
   {
       continue;
   }
 }

function calculate($counter){
    switch($counter){
         case 2:
          return false;
         default:
          echo "My remaining code lines";
         break;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I have updated my answer to move the loop to next iteration if the method `calculate()` `return`s `false`.

Comment: the switch case seems unnecessary

Comment: @Alex As the OP says he have alot of conditions and only 1 input variable, the switch might be more optimal here.

Comment: Indeed, missed that part!

Comment: Dear @mega6382, above said for-loop variable value can be dynamic. we don't know the range of values. so we can not use cases.

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement used.

```
for(condition){
   return();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) instead. It will return to the caller and hence you can continue execution.

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
   $this->calculate($i);
 }

 function calculate($counter){
    if($counter==2){
      return;
    }
    echo "My remaining code lines";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

// use return() function .. exit() stop execution ...

```
 function calculate($counter){
 if($counter==2){
  return;
 }
  echo "My remaining code lines";
}
?>
```